# How to read an unknown quantity of integers from console?

Tags: c, input, scanf

I have entries like these:

```
0 5 260
1 0 -598
1 5 1508
2 1 -1170
```

I don't know previously how many (console) inputs I'll get, so I have to read until there are no entries left.

I started with a code like this:

```
int a, b, c;
while(scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c)!=EOF){
    // do stuff here
}
```

But it never stops asking for new input.

Then, I saw people in other threads suggesting this:

```
int a, b, c;
while(scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c)==1){
    // do stuff here
}
```

In this case, it doesn't even enter the while.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `while(scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c) == 3) {` and then enter "Quit" when done.  Yet this is a broad answer.  How do you want to signal that there are no more? A blank line, Ctrl-D, "Quit", etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach:  Continue asking for input until the input is closed (EOF) or some problem is encountered.  (Invalid line of input)

The below uses `fgets()` to read a line.

Then, `" %n"` to detect where scanning stopped.  If scanning does not reach `%n`, `n` will still have the value of 0.  Otherwise it gets the offset in `buffer` where scanning stopped, hopefully it was at the null character `'\0'`.

```
char buffer[100];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buffer, "%d%d%d %n", &a, &b, &c, &n);
  if (n == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "3 int were not entered\n");
    break;
  }
  if (buffer[n] != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Extra input detected.\n");
    break;
  }
  // do stuff here with a,b,c
}
```

There are many approaches to solve this issue.

Comment: **It worked! Thanks!**
But as it is an automatic submission system and it is not online right now, I can't check if there's gonna be an extra line or something to mark the end of the inputs. But it needs something like this, right? Otherwise, there's no way to know when to give the output back to the user, right?

Comment: @plethora As mentioned, "There are many approaches to solve this issue." including `char sentinel; if(sscanf(buffer, "%d%d%d %c", &a, &b, &c, &sentinel)==3) good();` which would return 4 if there was extra.  Also non-`sscanf()` ways.  I find the `" %n"` simple to add to the end of a format convenient.

Comment: @plethora Deeper: Many users are only interest in first 2 of the 3 kinds of input: 1) Expected input with data 2) The last input that signifies no more and not 3) input that does not match the previous two.  Robust code detects group #3.

Comment: Got it... The "%n" approach is awesome indeed!

Comment: @plethora  Be sure to have a space in `" %n"` to first consume trailing white-space like `' '` or `'\n'` which are usually not a good reason to invalidate input.

Comment: Oh, I see... Thanks for emphasizing that, it would probably cause me future problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c)==1)
```

means that "if `scanf()` successfully read just one value, proceed in the loop."

Therefore, if you enter something like `0 junk`, the `scanf()` read just 1 data and will enter the loop once.

Try using

```
while(scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c)==3)
```

to have it enter the loop when `scanf()` successfully read three values, which is what expected.